# Ubuntu 20.04 still can't print on Kyocera FS1025MFP via usb

Tags: printing

I've managed to install the **Kyocera_FS-1025MFPGDI.ppd** in the **/usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera** folder successfully and copied the **rastertokpsl** file into the **/usr/lib/cups/filter** folder.

With printer on and usb plugged in I've tried to add printer and everything looked ok but I couldn't even print a test page. I removed printer and tried again and again.

Everything seems ok when printer is added but no printing at all. The troubleshoot wizard says there's no specific solution for my problem.

Printing test page gives message **Printing stopped 'Test page' on FS-1025MFP**

Answer (score 1):

This Kyocera line, FS-1x25MFP, or Aquarius, undermined Kyocera's reputation just greatly.
It can't scan over the network. I even could not make it scan through saned redirecting to local USB scan.
Moreover, it can not even serve as WIA/TWAIN source under Windows10, only can scan through a very limited interface of 'Kyocera Client Tool'.
And this is not going to be fixed by Kyocera, as they think they have completed driver development and achieved perfection in that around 2013.
Grieving over the fact that I approved purchase of 2 1025MFP basing on my good impressions from past Kyocera models.
Don't recommend anyone else to approach to these Aquariuses closer than 10 feet.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the driver for the FS-1025MFP printer in Ubuntu 20.04 as follows:

1. I downloaded the driver for Linux from Kuoser's official website:
   http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.ae/index/contact_support/dlc.false.driver.FS1025MFP._.EN.html#
2. Followed the attached instructions.

Now the FS-1025MFP printer connected via USB is working.

Comment: The link is dead